# ASP.NET Core 6 - How to take JSON input via MapPost() without deserializing?

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-core, curl

I am new to C#, JSON and web programming in general, so please correct me if I show signs of misunderstanding on certain concepts.

On ASP.NET Core 6, I want to use MapPost() to take a JSON string without having to deserialize it. I have previously made a class and successfully deserialized inputs, but now I want to try plain string. This is how part of my Web API's `Program.cs` looks like:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

Dictionary<string, string> mydictionary = new();

app.MapPost("/add_data/{queryKey}", (string queryKey, string jsonstring) =>
{
    mydictionary.Add(queryKey, jsonstring);
    return jsonstring;
});
```

An example of cURL API testing:

> curl -X POST 'https://localhost:5001/add_data/my_first_entry' -d
> '{"name":"Sebastian", "age":35, "car":"Renault"}' -H
> 'Content-Type: application/json'

expected response:

> '{"name":"Sebastian", "age":35, "car":"Renault"}'

Is it possible?

Comment: Allow me to challenge your priors: **Why** don't you want to deserialize it?

Comment: Plenty of use caases for dynamic content like config , routers , templates  all of node/js works that way as well and it dont break when you make changes. Could also ask the queston  Why do you ever want to serialzie it and start from basics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply add [FromBody] attribute to body and it will work as expected.

```
app.MapPost("/add_data/{queryKey}", (string queryKey, [FromBody] string jsonstring) =>
{
    mydictionary.Add(queryKey, jsonstring);
    return jsonstring;
});
```

Request:

```
POST /add_data/qq HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Host: localhost:7297
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21
 
"{ data = \"hello\"}"
```

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Right solution for raw requests:

```
app.MapPost("/add_data/{queryKey}", async delegate(HttpContext context)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        string queryKey = context.Request.RouteValues["queryKey"].ToString();
        string jsonstring = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        mydictionary.Add(queryKey, jsonstring);
        return jsonstring;
    }
});
```

Comment: The request you have shown is different to the request OP has presented. Are you sure your solution works in OP's case?

Comment: @Llama You are right, thank you for pointing me. I've updated answer